# Python3 - How can I determine the existence of element values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I determine the existence of element values ?

```
mylist = {
    "a" : { "aa" : "aaa",
            "ab" : "aba",
            "ac" : "aca" },

    "b" : { "ba" : "baa",
            "bb" : "bba",
            "bc" : "bca" },

    "c" : { "ca" : "caa",
            "cb" : "cba",
            "cc" : "cca" }
    }
```

## I tried

```
if "bba" in mylist["b"] :
  print('true')
else :
  print('false')
```

false

Why? Value "bba" in mylist["b"] does exist.
Advise anyone?
Thank you..

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've done it it's looking at the *keys* of the dict:

```
>>> 'a' in mylist
True
>>> 'foo' in mylist
False
```

Try this instead:

```
>>> 'bba' in mylist['b'].values()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

`if in` for dictionaries looks at the *keys* in the dictionary, not the *values*.

```
if "bba" in mylist["b"].values():
  print('true')
```

Answer (score 2):

`if "bba" in mylist["b"]` checks if `"bba"` is one of the *keys*, not the values.  Instead, use the `.values()` method:

```
if "bba" in mylist["b"].values():
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

To see that it is the keys that is checking, just take a look at the following example:

```
>>> dictionary = {'a': 4, 'b': 5}
>>> list(dictionary)
['a', 'b']
```

You see, when you iterate through the dictionary, you get all of the keys, but not any of the values.